# pyside add clickable item to QComboBox

Tags: python, events, pyside, qcombobox

I am wondering what's the best way to add a clickable item to a QComboBox() in PySide?

here my combobox function so far.

```
def setTreeWidgetsComboBox(self, index, items, currVariation, node=None):
    mainComboBoxWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
    mainComboBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.decayComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()


    mainComboBoxLayout.addWidget(self.decayComboBox)
    mainComboBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    mainComboBoxWidget.setLayout(mainComboBoxLayout)
    if len(items) != 1:     
        for x in items:
            try:
                i = x.split('_')[1]
            except:
                i = x
                continue

            self.decayComboBox.addItem(i)
    else:
        self.decayComboBox.addItem(items[0])



    i = self.decayComboBox.findText(currVariation, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
    if i >= 0:
        self.decayComboBox.setCurrentIndex(i)

    self.decayComboBox.addItem('new variation..')


    self.decayComboBox.setFixedHeight(20)
    self.nmcTableWidget.setIndexWidget(index, mainComboBoxWidget)

    return self.decayComboBox



    i = self.decayComboBox.findText(currVariation, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
    if i >= 0:
        self.decayComboBox.setCurrentIndex(i)

    self.decayComboBox.addItem('new variation..')


    self.decayComboBox.setFixedHeight(20)
    self.nmcTableWidget.setIndexWidget(index, mainComboBoxWidget)

    return self.decayComboBox
```

now I want the 'new variation..' entry to have a click event.
Do I have to overwrite the whole QComboBox Class with a custom delegate or is there some way to add the entry as QComboBox widget and make it clicked.connect?

sorry if that's a basic question. I'm still not very advanced in PySide.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

of course currentIndexChanged did the trick.